# Disable products archive on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to totally disable the product archives on my WP/WooCommerce install.

In the WooCommerce settings, I don't have anything set as the "Shop" page. However, when I visit mysite.com/shop , it shows an auto-populated product archive. It's showing up in Google search results too. How can I disable this? I don't want my users seeing all of the products on the site as it's a membership only site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WooCommerce registers the product post type, it sets the archive (`has_archive`) to the shop page ID if one has been set, otherwise it defaults to 'shop'. That is providing that the theme has declared that it supports WooCommerce. For themes that haven't made that declaration, it sets the archive to false instead.

Theme support is declared by using:

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

With that in mind, we can override the arguments passed in when registering the product post type to set `has_archive` to false. Here's a filter I wrote to do just that. This would be placed inside a theme's functions.php file or wherever else is most suitable.

```
function wpse_wc_disable_shop_archive( $post_type_args ) {
    $post_type_args['has_archive'] = false;
    return $post_type_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'wpse_wc_disable_shop_archive' );
```

Once you've implemented this code, be sure to flush your permalinks.

It is important for me to stress that I haven't tested the above code and its impact needs to be thoroughly understood. WooCommerce and various extensions may expect there to be a shop archive so you'll need to understand the effect of not having one. Do certain links such as "Continue Shopping" then break?

Also, the rationale you gave for hiding the shop page was that as a membership site, you don't want users seeing all of the products. There are various other ways that your full list of products will be exposed (e.g. the API or sitemap).

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan. I implemented your code which seems to have some effect - it basically dumbed down the layout of the /shop page, but it does still exist. Any further thoughts on this? In reference to your other concerns, I've set all products/posts to be nofollow on my sitemap.

Comment: Have you checked / deleted the "Shop" page under pages? It could be that you have an actual page with the slug shop that is now being shown. Flush your permalinks too (Settings -> Permalinks -> Save)

Comment: Flushing permalinks did the trick :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mickdeez no worries, I've added that to the answer for anyone else dealing with this